# Subviews of tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

У меня есть tableView, в котором ячейки имеют множественное наследование. Бывает такое, что ячейка не всегда прорисовывает свои элементы и отображается просто белая ячейка. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите код, сложно сказать в чем проблема, когда нет кода.

Comment: @Vitali Eller, Тут сложно показать код, потому что тут весь смысл в том, что у меня несколько наследований от UITableViewCell. Постараюсь обрисовать детально: У меня есть таблица, в которой есть кастомный селлы. Эти кастомные селлы наследуются от других кастомных селл. В некоторых селлах этой таблица, я на контент вью вставляю еще одну таблицу, в которой есть кастомная селла, которая наследуется от другой кастомной селлы. И вот в этом месте у меня редко, но бывает, что селла не рисует свои сабвью. А просто становится белой.

Comment: Никто не знает ?:(

Comment: Честно, очень сложно понять что происходит в коде. Первое что приходит на ум, это то, что в какой-то момент ячейка становиться nil. Попробуйте вывести дынные ячейки в логи и посмотрите какие там данные. Начнем отсюда

Comment: @VitaliEller, данные в ячейке есть, те которые там и должны быть. Но ячейка белая. Она перестает быть белой, только если я запущу приложение заново.

Comment: Какая-то тут завязка на layoutIfNeeded или что-то такое...

Comment: Возможно проблемы с frame. Посмотрите какик frame у элементов в ячейке, находятся ли они в приделах самой ячейки

Comment: @VitaliEller, увидел что контект в ячейке есть и он рисуется, но после определенных действий в этой селле появляются пустая вьюха над contentView. Чувствую ответ близок. Напишу как что-то еще будет известно. Не понимаю откуда берется эта вьюха, если я ее нигде не содаю.....

Comment: Может потому, что ячейки используются заново? Вью создается по верх прошлых вью.

Comment: @VitaliEller, все, вроде бы все работает) Да, дело было именно в переиспользовании ячейке. Из-за множественного наследования, забыл про prepareForReuse  в самой первой ячейке. Виталий,Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не так часто юзаю стекОверФлоу. Надо сейчас что-то теперь сделать после решения вопроса?

Comment: Добавлю свою идею как ответ, поставьте галочку, что он Вам помог. Рад, что нашли решение =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего проблема в том, что ячейки используются заново и возможно поверх уже существующего `view`, создается новое `view`.